# Where can I see samba registry share configuration from a system backup that's not running

Tags: samba

I have a backup of all files/folders from a Linux install that had Samba running and some shares.

This installation was using the registry for configuring the shares so they are not in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Where can I go to find the settings/shares that were configured? I can't boot into this system so that's not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry data should be saved under `/var/lib/samba/` in the "trivial database" files *.tdb

You can check the contents of that files with a `tdbtool`.

It should be possible to restore `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and `/var/lib/samba/*` to some other linux box and check the complete configuration using `sudo testparm`.